# How to implement Error Logging in Windows 8 METRO application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, error-logging

Hi i am developing an  windows 8  c#/xaml Metro application.

i want to implement error logging in my app. I want to handle error logs in better way.

1) How can log the error information(so that it will be helpful for the developer to rectify the error)

2)Are there any 3rd party tools / free library's for error logging in metro apps.

3)What are the various alternatives available for error logging ??

4)What is the best followed practice  for  error logging ??

Please help me out.

Your answer will be very helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 8.1 you can use the new Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics functionality of LoggingSession and LogginChannel.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/LoggingSession-Sample-ccd52336
See BUILD-session: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-136

```
var channel = new LoggingChannel ("ChannelName");
var session = new LoggingSession("Session Name");
session.AddLoggingChannel(channel, LoggingLevel.Warning);

channel.LogMessage("Message to log", LoggingLevel.Error);
channel.LogValuePair("Count", 42, LoggingLevel.Error);

//when error detected, save the log session to disk
var logFile = await session.SaveToFileAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "CrashLog");
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provide a [sample for logging](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7) maybe this will get you started.

In [this blog post](http://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/how-to-write-log-files-in-windows-store-apps/) the author names some starting points for setting up logging in a Windows8 Store App, as well as a homebrewed solution.