# How can I log LoggingChannel LogMessages to the StorageFile?

Tags: c#, logging, windows-store-apps, error-logging, storagefile

I want to add logging of exceptions to my Windows Store App. Based on an idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570364/how-to-implement-error-logging-in-windows-8-metro-%20application), I've started off with this code in App.xaml.cs:

sealed partial class App : Application
{
    private LoggingChannel channel;
    private LoggingSession session;

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
/// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
/// </summary>
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    channel = new LoggingChannel("PlatypiChannel");
    session = new LoggingSession("PlatypiSession");
    session.AddLoggingChannel(channel, LoggingLevel.Error);

    UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
}

async private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs ex)
{
    ex.Handled = true;
    String exceptionCornucopia = String.Format("Message0 == {0}; Message1 == {1}; HResult == {2}; Inner Ex == {3}; StackTrace == {4}", ex.Message, ex.Exception.Message, ex.Exception.HResult, ex.Exception.InnerException, ex.Exception.StackTrace);
    channel.LogMessage(exceptionCornucopia, LoggingLevel.Error);
    // not seeing how this saves the channel's logged messages...???
    StorageFile logFile = await session.SaveToFileAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "CrashLog");
}
```

As the comment indicates, it seems to me the last line simply saves a file named "CrashLog" to the LocalFolder. But how do the LogMessages get into that file? There is obviously a key piece missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this question has been open for a long time, but I just want to provide an answer for anyone else finding this.

The secret here is that the *LogMessages* are all written into the *LoggingChannel*, which itself has previously been registered with the *LoggingSession*:

> session.AddLoggingChannel(channel, LoggingLevel.Error);

When the session is then saved to a file, it obviously knows about the associated channels and where to search for pending log messages.